Find length of sequences of identical values along one axis in a 3D array (related to run length encoding)
I'm interested in finding the length of sequences of 1's along a single axis in a multi-dimension array.
For a 1D array I have worked my way to a solution using the answers at this older question. E.g. [0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1] --> [nan,1,nan,nan,3,nan,nan,nan,2,nan]
For a 3D array I can of course create a loop, but I'd rather not. (Background climate science, looping over all latitude/longitude grid cells is going to make this very slow.)
I'm trying to find a solution in line with the 1D solution. Help would be much appreciated, in line with the 1D code, but complete different solutions welcome too of course.
For reference, this is my working 1D solution:
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

def run_lengths(da):
    n = len(da)
    y = da.values[1:] != da.values[:-1]
    i = np.append(np.where(y), n - 1)
    z = np.diff(np.append(-1,i))
    p = np.cumsum(np.append(0,z))[:-1] 
    runs = np.where(da[i]==1)[0]
    runs_len = z[runs]           # length of sequence
    time_val = da.time[p[runs]]  # date of first day in sequence
    da_runs = xr.DataArray(runs_len,coords={'time':time_val})
    _,da_runs = xr.align(da,da_runs,join='outer') # make sure we have full time axis
    return da_runs

da = xr.DataArray(np.array([[[0,1,1,0,0,0],[1,0,1,1,0,1],[1,1,1,1,0,1]],[[0,1,1,0,0,0],[1,0,1,1,0,1],[1,1,1,1,0,1]]]),coords={'lat':[0,1],'lon':[0,1,2],'time':[0,1,2,3,4,5]})
da_runs = run_lengths(da[0,1])
print(da_runs)

<xarray.DataArray (time: 6)>
array([ 1., nan,  2., nan, nan,  1.])
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5


And this is the attempt in 3D. I'm stuck on how to shift the valid entries in i to the front/remove NaNs from i. (And maybe beyond that as well?)
def run_lengths_3D(da):
    n = len(da.time)
    y = da.values[:,:,1:] != da.values[:,:,:-1]
    y = xr.DataArray(y,coords={'lat':da.lat,'lon':da.lon,'time':da.time[0:-1]}) 
    i = y.where(y)*xr.DataArray(np.arange(0,len(da.time[0:-1])),coords={'time':y.time}) -1


please add a minimal, reproducible example. What is da?

@olivier-gauthé Thanks, I have added to the code example. Note here I created an artificial 3D-climate data array da, in reality it has size [256,512,3650].

Needs speed use numba. Still need to squeeze alittle more speed use optimized C. -- end up to be just a little better.

For this task you can try to use numba, e.g.:
import numba
import numpy as np


@numba.njit
def calculate(arr):
    out = np.empty_like(arr, dtype="uint16")

    lat, lon, time = arr.shape

    for i in range(lat):
        for j in range(lon):
            curr = 0
            for k in range(time):
                out[i, j, k] = 0
                if arr[i, j, k] == 0:
                    if curr > 0:
                        out[i, j, k - curr] = curr
                    curr = 0
                else:
                    curr += 1
            if curr > 0:
                out[i, j, -curr] = curr

    return out

arr = np.array(
    [
        [[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]],
        [[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]],
    ]
)
print(calculate(arr))

Prints:
[[[0 2 0 0 0 0]
  [1 0 2 0 0 1]
  [4 0 0 0 0 1]]

 [[0 2 0 0 0 0]
  [1 0 2 0 0 1]
  [4 0 0 0 0 1]]]


Benchmark using timeit + parallel version:
from timeit import timeit

import numba
import numpy as np


@numba.njit
def calculate(arr):
    out = np.empty_like(arr, dtype="uint16")

    lat, lon, time = arr.shape

    for i in range(lat):
        for j in range(lon):
            curr = 0
            for k in range(time):
                out[i, j, k] = 0
                if arr[i, j, k] == 0:
                    if curr > 0:
                        out[i, j, k - curr] = curr
                    curr = 0
                else:
                    curr += 1
            if curr > 0:
                out[i, j, -curr] = curr

    return out


@numba.njit(parallel=True)
def calculate_parallel(arr):
    out = np.empty_like(arr, dtype="uint16")

    lat, lon, time = arr.shape

    for i in range(lat):
        for j in numba.prange(lon):
            curr = 0
            for k in range(time):
                out[i, j, k] = 0
                if arr[i, j, k] == 0:
                    if curr > 0:
                        out[i, j, k - curr] = curr
                    curr = 0
                else:
                    curr += 1
            if curr > 0:
                out[i, j, -curr] = curr

    return out


arr = np.array(
    [
        [[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]],
        [[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]],
    ],
    dtype="uint8",
)

# compile calculate()/calculate_parallel()
assert np.allclose(calculate(arr), calculate_parallel(arr))

np.random.seed(42)
arr = np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=(256, 512, 3650), dtype="uint8")

t_serial = timeit("calculate(arr)", number=1, globals=globals())
t_parallel = timeit("calculate_parallel(arr)", number=1, globals=globals())

print(f"{t_serial * 1_000_000:.2f} usec")
print(f"{t_parallel * 1_000_000:.2f} usec")

Prints on my machine (AMD 5700x):
1575227.47 usec
320453.57 usec

